# Python Selenium driver.back() stops loop raise exception inside a loop

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, web-crawler

When I use an iterator over a list in python, and I click a link and go back to the parent page using driver.back, the loop variable becomes undefined , and the loop stops after first iteration and raises exception

Any tips to solve this issue

See the code below:

```
from selenium import  webdriver
import time
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait

driver = webdriver.Chrome("/Users/ahmed/Desktop/mixes/chromedriver.exe")
url  = 'https://www.premierleague.com/players'
divs = main2.find_elements(by = By.TAG_NAME, value="tr")
print(divs.__sizeof__())
for i in divs :
    print(i.text)
    link = i.find_element(by= By.TAG_NAME, value="a")
    link.click()
    club = driver.find_element(by= By.CLASS_NAME,value= "team")
    print(club.text)
    driver.back()
```

Comment: You could first extract all urls of the links to a separete list by a first loop.  Then directly loop over this list and open the pages directly.  so you don't need to use 'click()' and 'back()'

Comment: Some corrections needs to be done in your code, Please make sure you run this code in your compiler and figure out the errors. Also you can use xpath rather than css, and you need to handle popups as well. Please update the code